# Подсчет максимального элемента в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Как подсчитать максимальное число в столбце таблицы?

```
<?php
require_once "conf.php";
dbConnect();
$r=mysql_query("select max(num_cart) from cart") or die (mysql_error);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($r) ){
echo ($row['num_cart']);
}
?>
```

Вот это вот: `select max(num_cart) from cart` не работает. Вообще ничего не показывает.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT MAX(num_cart) as num FROM `cart`

echo $row['num'];
```

Answer (score 2):

и ошибочку поправьте, вот так правильно:

```
or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Выводите так:

```
echo mysql_result($query,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SELECT num_cart FROM cart ORDER BY num_cart DESC LIMIT 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Из вашего запроса непонятно зачем Вам нужен `while`?
Почему не выводит - потому, что нечего выводить(Вы хотите вывести строку `num_cart`, а запросили `max(num_cart)`, что не одно и тоже).

Правильный код:

```
$r=mysql_query("select max(num_cart) as max_num_cart from cart") or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
echo $row['max_num_cart']);
```

P.S.: кстати если запрос `select max(num_cart)` проверите через консоль mysql или phpmyadmin, результат будет.

**Дополнительно:**

> расширение mysql давно устарело([deprecated](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)). Используйте
>   [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) и [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), это проще и безопаснее.